# How do I listen for bluetooth events using Dbus?

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I'm developing a bluetooth applet for cinnamon and I want to have a way to toggle the bluetooth and do other basics like pairing, connect/disconnect etc

I've tried exploring the dbus protocol bluez offers but i couldn't figure out how to listen for power on/off events and how to actually issue commands using dbus, if that's even possible... :(

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

You can explore the tree using

```
busctl tree org.bluez
```

This will show you the node tree. You will have to enumerate the devices, and from that list select status for each one of them, and possibly enable/disable depending on your goals.

The [actual endpoints for adapters](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt) is listed in the [BlueZ DBUS documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc).

Further information can be found at https://ukbaz.github.io/howto/python_gio_1.html#dbus, which is geared towards Python, but should show you the basics. The code is fairly basic, so porting it to any language should be more or less trivial.

Comment: I'm gonna give this a try soon and report back with the results.

Answer (score -1):

Read `man hcitool bluetoothd bluetoothctl;man -k bluetooth;man -k bluez`.

If you find one with functions you like, take advantage of the Open Source nature of GNU/Linux!

An example, for `hcitool`:

```
# Don't do this in your $HOME, each package should have its own subdirectory
# determine the package containg the executable 
dpkg -S "$(type -p hcitool)"
pkg="$(dpkg -S "$(type -p hcitool) | head -n 1 | cut '-d:' -f1)"
# Retrieve the source
apt-get source "$pkg"
/bin/ls -l "${pkg}*"
```

Here's an explanation of what can be done with the "source".

In general, this process is called "building from source", and goes like this (assuming you have done `sudo apt install  build-essential`):

- Download (`apt-get source ...`) the archive (the `.tar.gz`). Put the file somewhere you can write, and on a filesystem with enough space. In the end, this file is disposable.
- Inspect the archive (`tar tzvf ...`, see `man tar`). Most unpack into a subdirectory. For the few that don't, `mkdir` your own subdirectory, `mv` the `.tar.gz` into it, and `cd` there.
- Unpack the archive (`tar xzvf ...`).
- Read the files with all upper case names (`README*`, `INSTALL`, ... ). They contain complete instructions, and override anything I type after this. Read the source (usually `./src/*`) to understand the program.
- If there's a `configure` script, run it (`./configure`). `configure` takes many options, see the `INSTALL` file or `./configure -h`. If `configure` succeeds, it will construct a `Makefike`.
- `make` compiles and links what is necessary. It produces an executable that can be tested before installation.
- This is the only step requiring `root` privileges: `sudo make install`. This command copies the executable, `man` pages, run-time necessities, to the "right" places.
- Once `sudo make install` has worked, the whole source directory is redundant, and may be deleted.

As always, YMMV.

Explore http://www.bluez.org/

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @vidarlo I told OP how to look through existing bluetooth tools, find one that does the function OP is looking for, how to find the Ubuntu package and download the source for the program. I told OP how to unpack the downloaded source, and evrn how to build it. OP can read the source, and see how other programmers did bluetooth things, which libraries it uses. No, it's not a "click here" Answer, rather it's a method that can be used to learn how things work.

Comment: But he's asking about dbus interface, not bluetooth tools. Furthermore, pointing someone to the source, without pointers to relevant parts of source, is next to useless. Usually it's *far* more relevant to read documentation.